# toast message is always on top of everything on screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap 4 toast messages to display success of operation status so I have the following in my html:

```
    <div id="successToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" autohide="true" aria-atomic="true" style="position: absolute; top:50vh; left:80vh">
    <div class="toast-body" style="background-color: #1be611">
        &#10004; Product added successfully
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$.ajax({

//lot of code

success: function () {
            $('#successTost').toast('show');
}
});
```

but the problem is the toast message is always visible and not getting triggered, in other words it is just still there over all other elements.
when I try to initiate it display with none when success executes it never shows.
would you please kindly tell me what is wrong? is there something I am missing about bootstrap's toast messages? how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure could you add some runnable code to help us reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm looking at your code correctly all you would need is a `display: none;` on your successToast element to get this to work. Id recommend from a UI perspective to include a close button on your toast as well so it can be dismissed.